# How to save search query result into the model with Django?

Tags: python, django

This is to revert/rollback the table.

I have a query like this:

```
query = Table.objects.all()
```

it takes all entries in the Table. I will delete it later:

```
Table.objects.all().delete()
```

Now I want to save the query into Table. How can I do that?

Comment: as in, saving the hard SQL query? Because `delete()` will update the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save by `Table.save()`
for more details you can read [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)